# How to encrypt all existing stored procedures of a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, encryption, sqlcmd

Is there any possibility to encrypt all existing stored procedures of a SQL Server 2008 database AFTER they have been created via an SQLCMD script?

The reason I want to do this is the following:
I'd like to develop the stored procedures without encryption so I can easily click on "Modify" in SQL Server Management Studio to check their contents.
However, for the deployment I'd like to encrypt them so I thought that maybe I could write a script which encrypts them only after they're created. For dev systems I simply wouldn't run the script while on end-user systems the script would be run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem.

My solution is to put "-- WITH ENCRYPTION" in all of my stored procedures.  This version is used by developers and stored in source control.

I then use a tool (like sed) in my build to replace "-- WITH ENCRYPTION" with "WITH ENCRYPTION" on the files before I send them to be installed.

For a pure SQL solution you could use REPLACE.

Comment: We do something similar, but we also replace `-- , ENCRYPTION` which allows us to have additional WITH properties such as `WITH SCHEMABINDING -- , ENCRYPTION`

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check [Encrypting all the Stored Procedures of a Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/239100/Encrypting-all-the-Stored-Procedures-of-a-Database) :

> If you ever decide that you need to protect your SQL Stored
> Procedures, and thought encrypting was a good idea, BE VERY CAREFUL!!!
> Encrypting Database stored procedures SHOULD NOT be done without
> having backup files or some sort of Source Control for the stored
> procedures. The reason I say this is because, once they are encrypted,
> there is no turning around. (Yes, there are third party tools that
> will decrypt your code, but Why go through that trouble.)
>
> This trick is something I developed because my company needed to host the application on a different server, and we were concerned
> about our code being compromised. So, to deliver the database, we
> decided to encrypt all out stored procedures. Having over a hundred
> procedures written, I didn't want to open each procedure and paste
> 'WITH ENCRYPTION' in each and every stored procedure. (For those of
> you who do not know how to encrypt, refer How Do I Protect My Stored
> Procedure Code[^]). So I decided to make my own little C# application
> that did the same.
>
> This application is a console application made
> using Visual Studio 2005 and SQL server 2005. The input parameters are
> database name, Server address, database username and password. Once
> you are able to provide these details, you are ready to have all your
> stored procedures encrypted.
>
> I have put the code of my application
> here as is. For this code to work, you will need to add an
> "Microsft.SQlserver.SMO" refrence to the application, so that the
> classes such as "Database" and "StoredProcedure" are accessible.
>
> ```
> BEFORE YOU DO THIS, TAKE A BACKUP!!!!!!!
> ```

```csharp
//Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
string DB = "";
ServerConnection objServerCOnnection = new ServerConnection();
objServerCOnnection.LoginSecure = false;
Console.WriteLine("Enter name or IP Address of the Database Server.");
objServerCOnnection.ServerInstance = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter name of the Database");
DB = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter user id");
objServerCOnnection.Login = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
objServerCOnnection.Password = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(" ");
Server srv = new Server();
try // Check to see if server connection details are ok.
{
   srv = new Server(objServerCOnnection);
   if (srv == null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Server details entered are wrong,"
         + " Please restart the application");
      Console.ReadLine();
      System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
   }
}
catch
{
   Console.WriteLine("Server details entered are wrong,"
      + " Please restart the application");
   Console.ReadLine();
   System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
}
Database db = new Database();
try // Check to see if database exists.
{
   db = srv.Databases[DB];
   if (db == null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Database does not exist on the current server,"
         + " Please restart the application");
      Console.ReadLine();
      System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
   }
}
catch
{
   Console.WriteLine("Database does not exist on the current server,"
      + " Please restart the application");
   Console.ReadLine();
   System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
}
string allSP = "";
                
for (int i = 0; i < db.StoredProcedures.Count; i++)
{
   //Define a StoredProcedure object variable by supplying the parent database 
   //and name arguments in the constructor. 
   StoredProcedure sp;
   sp = new StoredProcedure();
   sp = db.StoredProcedures[i];
   if (!sp.IsSystemObject)// Exclude System stored procedures
   {
      if (!sp.IsEncrypted) // Exclude already encrypted stored procedures
      {
         string text = "";// = sp.TextBody;
         sp.TextMode = false;
         sp.IsEncrypted = true;
         sp.TextMode = true;
         sp.Alter();
 
         Console.WriteLine(sp.Name); // display name of the encrypted SP.
         sp = null;
         text = null;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a really great snippet of code, thank you so much.  Just getting into SMO and loving it.  Thanks again for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

`WITH ENCRYPTION` means that the code behind the proc is not stored in the SysComments table.

You could write a script that does a `exec sp_helptext 'MyProcName'` and gets the contents into a **VarChar (MAX)** so it can hold multiline / large procedures easily and then modifiy the procedure from it's original state

```
CREATE MyProcName AS

SELECT SecretColumns From TopSecretTable
```

change `CREATE` to `ALTER` and `AS` surrounded by space or tab or newline  (good place to use Regular Expressions) to `WITH ENCRYPTION AS`

```
ALTER MyProcName WITH ENCRYPTION AS

SELECT SecretColumns From TopSecretTable
```

This will hide all code for the stored proc on the production server.

You can put this in a `LOOP` or a `CURSOR` (not really a set based operation IMHO) for all objects of a specific type and/or naming convention that you want to encrypt, and run it every time you deploy.

Comment: There are two problems with this.  

1) Parameters in the stored procedure go between the ALTER/CREATE and the WITH commands.
2) Long stored procedures may be stored in multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you for the information about `SysComments` table. I didn't know this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating the sproc in a multi-line string variable and then inserting or altering it using `sp_executesql`. The only annoying downside to this approach is doubling of single quotes for strings.

```
DECLARE @action varchar(max);
SET @action = 'CREATE'; /* or "ALTER" */

DECLARE @withEncryption varchar(max);
SET @withEncryption = ''; /* or "WITH ENCRYPTION" */

DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
SET @sql = @action + ' PROCEDURE dbo.Something'
    (
        ....
    ) ' + @withEncryption +
    ' AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @bob varchar(10);
        SET @bob = ''Bob'';
        ....
    END;
    ';

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sql;
```

[Note the whitespace around the variables.]

All of my scripts use this method, which works well once you get used to the quote doubling thing.

I also use a batch file to call the script, and SQLCMD-mode command line variables to select various behaviours, which makes it repeatable and easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Query which Encrypt All Procedures in database

```
    CREATE TABLE #backup
(
id BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1),
sptext NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
spname NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
encrypttext NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
encryptstatus BIT NOT NULL
DEFAULT ( 0 )
)
DECLARE @sptexttable TABLE
(
id BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1),
sptext NVARCHAR(MAX),
spname NVARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @sptexttable ( sptext, spname )
SELECT [text],
[name]
FROM syscomments
JOIN sysobjects ON syscomments.id = sysobjects.id
AND sysobjects.xtype = 'p'
DECLARE @sptext NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @spname NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 1
WHILE @counter <= ( SELECT MAX(id)
FROM @sptexttable
)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO #backup ( sptext, spname )
SELECT sptext,
spname
FROM @sptexttable
WHERE id = @counter
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [name]
FROM sysobjects
WHERE [name] = 'ce_LastIndexOf'
AND xtype = 'FN' ) 
BEGIN


EXEC
( 'CREATE FUNCTION ce_LastIndexOf
(
@strValue VARCHAR(4000),
@strChar VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @index INT


SET @index = 0


WHILE CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue) > 0
BEGIN
SET @index = @index
+ CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue) > 1
THEN ( LEN(@strValue) - LEN(SUBSTRING(@strValue,
CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue)
+ LEN(@strChar),
LEN(@strValue))) )
ELSE 1
END
SET @strValue = SUBSTRING(@strValue,
CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue)
+ LEN(@strChar), LEN(@strValue))
END
RETURN @index
END'
)


END
DECLARE @tempproc NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @procindex INT
DECLARE @beginindex INT
DECLARE @header NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @asindex INT
DECLARE @replacetext NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tempproc = ( SELECT sptext
FROM @sptexttable
WHERE id = @counter
)

IF ( SELECT CHARINDEX('CREATE PROC', UPPER(@tempproc))
) > 0 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
SELECT @procindex = CHARINDEX('PROC', UPPER(@tempproc))
PRINT @procindex
SELECT @beginindex = CHARINDEX('BEGIN', UPPER(@tempproc))
PRINT @beginindex
SELECT @header = SUBSTRING(@tempproc, @procindex,
@beginindex - @procindex)
SELECT @asindex = ( SELECT dbo.ce_lastindexof(@header, 'AS')
- 2
)
SELECT @replacetext = STUFF(@header, @asindex, 10,
CHAR(13) + 'WITH ENCRYPTION'
+ CHAR(13) + 'AS' + CHAR(13))
SET @tempproc = REPLACE(@tempproc, @header, @replacetext)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
END

UPDATE @sptexttable
SET sptext = @tempproc
WHERE id = @counter


--PLAY HERE TO M AKE SURE ALL PROCS ARE ALTERED
UPDATE @sptexttable
SET sptext = ( SELECT REPLACE(sptext, 'CREATE PROC',
'ALTER PROC')
FROM @sptexttable
WHERE id = @counter
)
WHERE id = @counter
SELECT @sptext = sptext,
@spname = spname
FROM @sptexttable
WHERE id = @counter
BEGIN TRY
EXEC ( @sptext
)
UPDATE #backup
SET encrypttext = @sptext,
encryptstatus = 1
WHERE id = @counter
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'the stored procedure ' + @spname
+ ' cannot be encrypted automatically'
END CATCH
SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
SELECT *
FROM #backup
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a cursor, steps through and encrypts most objects.

```
                            DECLARE cur_ENCRYPT_ANTHING CURSOR READ_ONLY
                            FOR
                                    SELECT  STUFF(src.definition,
                                                  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('AS' + CHAR(13),src.definition,1) = 0
                                                       THEN CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('AS ' + CHAR(13),src.definition,1) = 0 THEN CHARINDEX('AS ',src.definition,1)
                                                                 ELSE CHARINDEX('AS ' + CHAR(13),src.definition,1)
                                                            END
                                                       ELSE CHARINDEX('AS' + CHAR(13),src.definition,1)
                                                  END,3,'WITH ENCRYPTION AS' + CHAR(13))
                                    FROM    (SELECT o.name
                                             ,      STUFF(RIGHT(sm.definition,LEN(sm.definition) - CHARINDEX('CREATE ',sm.definition,1) + 1),1,6,'ALTER') AS definition
                                             FROM   sys.sql_modules AS sm
                                                    JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
                                             WHERE  CAST(CASE WHEN sm.definition IS NULL THEN 1
                                                              ELSE 0
                                                         END AS BIT) = 0
                                                    AND type <> 'TR'
                                            ) AS src








                            DECLARE @VLS NVARCHAR(MAX)
                            OPEN cur_ENCRYPT_ANTHING

                            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ENCRYPT_ANTHING INTO @VLS
                            WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
                                  BEGIN
                                        IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
                                           BEGIN
                                                 BEGIN TRY
                                                       EXEC (@VLS)

                                                 END TRY
                                                 BEGIN CATCH
                                                       PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
                                                       PRINT ''

                                                       PRINT @VLS
                                                 END CATCH
                                           END
                                        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ENCRYPT_ANTHING INTO @VLS
                                  END

                            CLOSE cur_ENCRYPT_ANTHING
                            DEALLOCATE cur_ENCRYPT_ANTHING
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made an update to one of the above answers by removing the dependency on the initial Begin Tag. I had a situation where not all my stored procedures had BEGIN and END.

I used the AS clause instead and also used a case sensitive version of the charindex (by adding a collation)

Its not a perfect solution but helped in getting more of my stored procedures encrypted.

Here is my updated code:

```
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#backup', 'U') IS NOT NULL 

             BEGIN

             DROP TABLE #backup

             END

            CREATE TABLE #backup

             (

             id BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1),

             sptext NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,

             spname NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

             encrypttext NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

             encryptstatus BIT NOT NULL

             DEFAULT ( 0 )

             )

            DECLARE @sptexttable TABLE

             (

             id BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1),

             sptext NVARCHAR(MAX),

             spname NVARCHAR(100)

             )

            INSERT INTO @sptexttable ( sptext, spname )

             SELECT [text],

             [name]

             FROM syscomments

             JOIN sysobjects ON syscomments.id = sysobjects.id

             AND sysobjects.xtype = 'p'

            DECLARE @sptext NVARCHAR(MAX)

            DECLARE @spname NVARCHAR(100)

            DECLARE @counter INT

            SET @counter = 1

            WHILE @counter <= ( SELECT MAX(id)

             FROM @sptexttable

             )

             BEGIN





             BEGIN TRY





             INSERT INTO #backup ( sptext, spname )

             SELECT sptext,

             spname

             FROM @sptexttable

             WHERE id = @counter

             END TRY

             BEGIN CATCH

             END CATCH

              IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [name]

             FROM sysobjects

             WHERE [name] = 'CaseSensitiveIndex'

             AND xtype = 'FN' ) 

             BEGIN
                

             EXEC (
             'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CaseSensitiveIndex(@source nvarchar(max), @pattern VARCHAR(50))
            RETURNS int
            BEGIN  
                return   CHARINDEX(@pattern COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, @source COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) 
            END; '
            )
            end


             IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [name]

             FROM sysobjects

             WHERE [name] = 'ce_LastIndexOf'

             AND xtype = 'FN' ) 

             BEGIN

                

             EXEC

             ( 'CREATE FUNCTION ce_LastIndexOf 

                (@strValue VARCHAR(max),

                @strChar VARCHAR(50)) 

            RETURNS INT

            AS

            BEGIN

            DECLARE @index INT

                

            SET @index = 0



            WHILE CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue) > 0

                BEGIN

                    SET @index = @index + CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue) > 1 

                                 THEN 

                                    (LEN(@strValue) - LEN(SUBSTRING(@strValue,CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue) + LEN(@strChar),LEN(@strValue)))) 

                                 ELSE 

                                    1 

                                 END

                    SET @strValue = SUBSTRING(@strValue,CHARINDEX(@strChar, @strValue) + len(@strChar),LEN(@strValue))    

                END



                RETURN @index 

            END'

             )



             END 

             DECLARE @tempproc NVARCHAR(MAX) 

             DECLARE @procindex INT

             DECLARE @beginindex INT

             DECLARE @header NVARCHAR(MAX)

             DECLARE @asindex INT

             DECLARE @replacetext NVARCHAR(MAX)



             SET @tempproc = ( SELECT sptext

             FROM @sptexttable

             WHERE id = @counter

             )



             IF ( SELECT CHARINDEX('CREATE PROC', UPPER(@tempproc))

             ) > 0 

             BEGIN

             BEGIN TRY

             SELECT @procindex = CHARINDEX('PROC', UPPER(@tempproc))

             PRINT @procindex

             SELECT @beginindex=(select dbo.CaseSensitiveIndex(@tempproc, 'AS'))


             if(@beginindex=0) begin set @beginindex=( SELECT dbo.ce_lastindexof(@tempproc, 'AS'))end
             SELECT @header = SUBSTRING(@tempproc, @procindex,

             @beginindex )

             SELECT @asindex = ( SELECT dbo.ce_lastindexof(@header, 'AS')

             - 2

             )

             SELECT @replacetext = STUFF(@header, @asindex, 3,

             CHAR(13) + 'WITH ENCRYPTION'

             + CHAR(13) + 'AS' + CHAR(13))

             SET @tempproc = REPLACE(@tempproc, @header, @replacetext)



                                



             END TRY

             BEGIN CATCH

             END CATCH



                

             END



             UPDATE @sptexttable

             SET sptext = @tempproc

             WHERE id = @counter 



            --PLAY HERE TO MAKE SURE ALL PROCS ARE ALTERED

             UPDATE @sptexttable

             SET sptext = ( SELECT REPLACE(sptext, 'CREATE PROC',

             'ALTER PROC')

             FROM @sptexttable

             WHERE id = @counter

             )

             WHERE id = @counter 



             SELECT @sptext = sptext,

             @spname = spname

             FROM @sptexttable

             WHERE id = @counter


             BEGIN TRY


             EXEC ( @sptext)

             UPDATE #backup

             SET encrypttext = @sptext,

             encryptstatus = 1

             WHERE id = @counter

             END TRY

             BEGIN CATCH

             PRINT 'the stored procedure ' + @spname

             + ' cannot be encrypted automatically'

             END CATCH





             SET @counter = @counter + 1

             END

            SELECT *

            FROM #backup where encryptstatus =0
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I export Create code for SP and functions. Keep it backed up. for example D:\SP2.sql"

2) this transact  SQL code, generate the script to delete existing sP & Functions

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE  [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'  as A
FROM sys.procedures p
union
SELECT  'DROP FUNCTION ' + [name]  
FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0
order by a
```

3) This Poweshell code 
replace

```
AS
BEGIN
```

by

```
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS
BEGIN
```

The code

```
$File = "D:\SP2.sql"
$File2 = $File.Replace("SP2.sql","SP-WithEncrypt.sql")
$sortie=""
$SP = get-content -path $file
echo $SP.Count
For ($i = 0 ; $i -le $SP.Count)
{ if ($sp[$i] -eq "AS" -and $sp[$i+1] -eq "BEGIN")
   { $AEcrire = "`nWITH ENCRYPTION `n AS `n BEGIN"
   $i+=1 
          }
   else
   {$AEcrire =$sp[$i]
   }
   $sortie += "`n$AEcrire"

 $i+=1 
 $SP.Count-$i
}

$sortie| out-file $File2
```

Would be faster with a .replace( ,), but problem with End of lines...

4) run the SP-WithEncrypt.sql in SSMS