# Encrypt all existing Stored Procedures with PowerShell sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, stored-procedures, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to encrypt all stored procedures in existing database
so i tried with shell scripts

```
$db = (new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("SQL_instance")).Databases.Item("[DB_name]") 

Foreach ($sp in $db.StoredProcedures){
  if(!$sp.IsSystemObject){
    if (!$sp.IsEncrypted){
        $sp.TextMode = $false;
        $sp.IsEncrypted = $true;
        $sp.TextMode = $true;
        try
{
            $sp.Alter();
}
catch{
Write-Host "$sp.Name fail to encrypted."
}

     }
  }
}
```

it is working on one of my local server but not on client's server
[Source for this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434183/Encrypt-all-Stored-Procedures-with-PowerShell)

i am getting following error
[image: Error]

Comment: "I want to encrypt all stored procedures in existing database " -what could possibly go wrong!

Comment: @MitchWheat is there any different versions for shellscripts??

Comment: Please [do not assume](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7671944/503046) the encryption is, well, secure.

Comment: Try this, 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8478071/930186
Its not PowerShell, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

You script works fine for me - so I would suspect that you may need to run powershell in administrator mode or elevate its privileges..